# Retrieve HTML Element Value Using Clojure

Tags: javascript, html, clojure, getelementbyid

I am new to web development, and I am using Clojure as my backend language.

I'm trying to move my user authentication from frontend to backend, and I'm attempting to retrieve the value from an HTML password field.

So I'm wondering, is there a Clojure equivalent of `document.getElementById('foo').value`?

Comment: I think you misunderstand something : the server does not have access to the DOM. You have to make some kind of request (ex AJAX) to send the data to the server.

Comment: Oh ok I understand, so I have to post a request to the server and handle that in the backend language?

Comment: Yes. And reply adequately. I answered with a bit more details, but you will have to read up on the subject. I am voting to close the question, since it was primarily based on a misconception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you misunderstand something : the server does not have access to the DOM.

You have to make some kind of request (ex AJAX) to send the data to the server.
   It goes like this :

```
   Browser -> request with credentials           -> Server (Clojure)
                                                    (does it's thing, maybe talk to a DB)
   Browser <- response validating the data or not <- Server
```

You will have to read up on the subject for more information.

*Note :* it would be totally doable in ClojureScript to replace JavaScript though :

```
(defn by-id [id]
  (.getElementById js/document (name id)))

(by-id "foo")
```

Comment: Though it is a viable solution to implement the JavaScript in Clojure, I would like to keep the two languages separate as JavaScript is a front end language and Clojure is a back end language. But thank you for that solution, and for anyone who is willing to accept JS code in their Clojure code, that solution does indeed work. Thanks!